# PostgreSQL recursive rows to JSONB map

Tags: json, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, jsonb

This question is best explained with an example.  So, if you have 2 tables `category` and `event` in PostgreSQL as follows: -

```
create table category (
    id integer primary key,
    type varchar(255),
    label varchar (255),
    parent_id integer
);
insert into category (id, type,           label,    parent_id) 
              values (1,  'organisation', 'Google', null),
                     (2,  'product',      'Gmail',  1),
                     (3,  'organisation', 'Apple',  null),
                     (4,  'product',      'iPhone', 3),
                     (5,  'product',      'Mac',    3);

create table event (
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar (255),
    category_id integer
);
insert into event (id, name, category_id) 
           values (1,  'add', 4),
                  (2,  'delete', 5),
                  (3,  'update', 2);
```

As you can see, the `category` table is quite dynamic and a hierarchy of categories can be defined.

What I'm trying to achieve is selecting entries of the `event` table and join it with the categories but flatten it to a JSON structure.  I can illustrate using the following query: -

```
select e.*, 
       jsonb_build_object( 
           c1.type, c1.label,
           c2.type, c2.label
       ) as categories
  from event e
  left join category c2 on c2.id = e.category_id
  left join category c1 on c1.id = c2.parent_id
```

This will return: -

```
+----+--------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | name   | category_id | categories                                     |
+----+--------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | add    | 4           | {"organisation": "Apple", "product": "iPhone"} |
| 2  | delete | 5           | {"organisation": "Apple", "product": "Mac"}    |
| 3  | update | 2           | {"organisation": "Google", "product": "Gmail"} |
+----+--------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

However, this approach only works when an `event.category_id` column references a child category which has precisely 1 parent (2 levels).  Really what I'm looking for is to generate `categories`, regardless if (a) it doesn't have a parent category (i.e. a 1 level category) OR (b) has more than 1 parent (e.g. 3 levels).  For example, if I add the following rows to the `event` and `category` tables: -

```
insert into category (id, type,           label,    parent_id) 
              values (6,  'module',       'Mobile', 5),    /* has 2 parents  */
                     (7,  'organisation', 'AirBNB', null); /* has no parents */

insert into event (id, name, category_id) 
           values (4,  'event1', 6),
                  (5,  'event2', 7);
```

... and run the query from above it will return: -

```
ERROR: argument 1: key must not be null
SQL state:
```

My gut feeling is a recursive CTE could solve this.

---

### Update 1

```
 create or replace function category_array(category_parent_id int) returns setof jsonb as $$
     select case
         when count(x) > 0 then
              jsonb_agg(f.x) || jsonb_build_object (
                  c.type, c.label
              )
         else jsonb_build_object (
                  c.type, c.label
              )
      end as category_pair
 from category c
 left join category_array (c.parent_id) as f(x) on true
where c.id = category_parent_id
group by c.id, c.type, c.label;

$$ language sql;
```

... and call using this SQL ...

```
select *, 
       category_array(category_id) 
  from event;
```

... will return the following ...

```
+----+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name   | category_id | categories                                                               |
+----+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | add    | 4           |  [{"organisation": "Apple"}, {"product": "iPhone"}]                      |
| 2  | delete | 5           |  [{"organisation": "Apple"}, {"product": "Mac"}]                         |
| 3  | update | 2           |  [{"organisation": "Google"}, {"product": "Gmail"}]                      |
| 4  | event1 | 6           |  [[{"organisation": "Apple"}, {"product": "Mac"}], {"module": "Mobile"}] |
| 5  | event2 | 7           |  {"organisation": "AirBNB"}                                              |
+----+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Pretty close but not quite there just yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [concatenation operator ||](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to build cumulative jsonb objects:

```
with recursive events as (
    select 
        e.id, e.name, e.category_id as parent_id,
        jsonb_build_object(c.type, c.label) as categories
    from event e
    left join category c on c.id = e.category_id
union all
    select 
        e.id, e.name, c.parent_id,
        categories || jsonb_build_object(c.type, c.label)
    from events e
    join category c on c.id = e.parent_id
)

select id, name, categories 
from events
where parent_id is null
order by id;
```

Note that the query is not protected against circular dependencies, so you need to be sure that all paths in the table are ended with nulls.

Test the query on [DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f9a724abcffe645bdd292266021fc28e)

---

Alternative solution:

```
create or replace function get_categories(int) 
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select case
        when parent_id is null then
            jsonb_build_object (type, label)
        else 
            jsonb_build_object (type, label) || get_categories(parent_id)
    end as categories
    from category
    where id = $1
$$;

select id, name, get_categories(category_id)
from event
order by id;
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c12c22509fd189d225e0f49c374ad302)

Comment: Perfect, I initially tried recursive CTE, then tried a function, thank you for the clear and precise solution!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Your function was really close, though it may be much simpler.